# Edit templates in Bigcommerce via api

Tags: api, templates, bigcommerce

Is there any way to edit templates (layouts, panels, snippets) of the *Bigcommerce* store via api?

Answer (score 1):

No. You can edit via the online editor in the dashboard or you can edit offline and push the files back in via WebDAV.